# Using MariaDB's 'DATE_FORMAT' within a Django Query Expression

Tags: python, django, datetime, mariadb

Good afternoon, I'm trying to use the `DATE_FORMAT` [(reference)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) function provided by MariaDB to convert a `datetime` field to `str` directly from the database;

```
# Dummy Model
class FooBar(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

# Query
FooBar.objects.all().annotate(dt_field=Func('datetime', Value("'%W %M %Y'"), function='DATE_FORMAT'))
```

If I check the resulting query the output is as expected.

```
>>> print(FooBar.objects.annotate(str_date=Func('datetime', Value("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"), function='DATE_FORMAT')).query)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`foobar`.`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') AS `str_date` FROM `foobar`
```

However, the actual execution of the query fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 74, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1096, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 265, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 270, in make_aware
    return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 237, in localize
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

I must be doing or assuming something incorrectly, any advice?

Comment: This looks a bit *odd*: a database is not meant for formatting, but for storing, manipulating and aggregating *data*. Rendering should be done by the template, not by the database/models.

Comment: I'm actually retrieving more fields before passing them to a view and I thought it would be more performant if the data comes already formatted.

Comment: well normally that is not the bottleneck. The idea of Python is that *developer's time is more costly than processing time*. In other words, one should focus on big oh and the number of queries, not on a few cycles, since it costs developers a lot of money to get these correct, and often the "gain" is very limited. Hiring a new developer is costly, buying a new machine is cheap.

Comment: Furthermore Django already has a lot of tooling builtin. For example to format datetimes in the user's locale. You can use the [`|date` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) to filter it in a specific format, but you can also use the user's locale, such that a German user will see the date formatted according to German standards, and a Mexican user to Mexican standards.

Comment: Did you install timezone support in MariaDB? (mysql_tzinfo_to_sql utitliy) ?